# Lumen 8 CORS issue Decemeber 2020

Tags: cors, lumen

I have issue with CORS using Lumen 8.

I've created CorsMiddleware.php as this =>

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => getenv('ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN'),
            // 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => getenv('ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS'),
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => '86400',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        ];

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Added it in my bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class,
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,

]);
```

I've even add to my .htaccess

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
Header set  Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

but as useless as the rest...

And weird, Postman access to my routes !? But my local app can't...

Do you guys have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Cors middleware, I think you should add it in $app->middleware([]). This is what we've done in our project before.

```php
$app->middleware([
    App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class
]);
```

The `$app->middleware([]}` is a global middleware and this really works very good especially when dealing with HTTP Requests.

If you would like to assign middleware to specific routes, you should first assign the middleware a short-hand key in bootstrap/app.php file's call to the `$app->routeMiddleware()`. Mostly `'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,` are mostly being past here because you dealing with routes. So authenticate for protection.

#ref: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware

Comment: Thanks @JenuelGanawed, you saved my time.